# Help interpreting this bit of Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is this?

```
"#{h params[:chat_input]}"
```

I am referring to the hash `#` and the `h`.

Answer (score 8):

Most likely this is inside a double-quoted string, such as `"Ponies all love #{h params[:chat_input]}!"`  The `#{stuff}` expression causes the stuff expression to be interpreted and inserted into the string.  For example `"1 + 2 = #{1 + 2}"` will result in the string `"1 + 2 = 3"`.

The `h` is an alias to the [`html_escape`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#M000300) method, which is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: also, #{} is ruby, not rails specific

Answer (score 4):

The code you paste, by itself, is just a comment. I assume the code is inside a string, though.

```
"hello, #{5 + 5}"
# => hello, 10
```

The statement inside the brackets will be evaluated as Ruby. This is called string interpolation.

The statement inside the interpolation in your code is a method that gets an argument.

```
h params[:chat_input]
h(params[:chat_input])
```

The `h` method is a shortcut for `html_escape`, which escapes HTML. For example, `<span>` is converted into `&lt;span&gt;`, so that the browser displays the actual contents of the string, instead of interpreting it as HTML.

```
html_escape(params[:chat_input])
```

You probably know what `params` is.

To sum up, you get a HTML escaped version of whatever params[:chat_input] contains.

Answer (score 4):

"#{h params[:chat_input]}"

In ruby, double-quoted strings allow for expressions to be evaluated and automatically converted to strings.

I can do this:

```
years = 25
"John is " + years +  " years old"
```

but I'll get an error because I can't add the number to a string.

I can do

```
"John is #{years} years old"
```

to get around that.

The h() method is a Rails helper function that removes HTML tags. It's a safety thing.

Finally, params() is a method in Rails that gives you access to GET and POST parameters.  It's actually wrapping a hash GET and POST parameters are symbolized to reduce memory (symbols are only defined once, whereas a string like "foo" is a new object every time.)

So, params[:chat_input]  retrieves the value from the previous request's GET or POST parameters, and in your case it looks like it's just displaying and sanitizing them.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's just interpolating a value inside a string. The :chat_input is a symbol, it's used in place of a string because symbols are only created once.

Answer (score 1):

```
h(something)
```

or

```
h something
```

since ruby does not force the use of (), is a function available in rails that converts the parameter to a "safe HTML" string avoiding interpreting the possible HTML code inside of the 'something' variable.

```
"#{x}"
```

in ruby means converting the x variable to a string and placing it in the new string for example:

```
"#{host}:#{port}"
```

will place the value of host and the value of port into the new string formed by the "", in a way that if host is "localhost" and port is 30 the result string will be "localhost:30"

params is a special rails hash that contains the post/get parameters passed to the controller method being executed

another detail is that in ruby a method always returns the last evaluated expression

so the method

```
def test
   "#{h params[:chat_input]}"
end
```

will return a string that has the HTML-safe value of the post/get parameter chat_input

Answer (score 0):

holy crap, is that from [chat_sandbox](http://github.com/taelor/chat_sandbox) by any chance?

if so, let me know if you need any help $)

I'm hoping to update that code here soon.